# What happened to the Kyuubi's chakra after Orochimaru releases the Dead Demon Consuming Seal?

Tags: naruto

We know that when the Kyuubi attacked Konoha, the 4th Hokage sealed half of the Kyuubi's chakra using the Dead Demon Consuming Seal and half within Naruto.

When Orochimaru sliced the stomach of the Dead Demon Consuming Seal "Reaper"/Shinigami (Chapter 618), all things that was sealed in it was freed.

So what happened to the half of the Kyuubi's chakra that was sealed? Why didn't it return?

Comment: What makes you think it didn't return? The manga has not gone back to the Kyuubi and Naruto since Orochimaru did that. I suspect we will find out almost as soon as the arc returns to them.

Comment: @Oded The manga has returned to them already, Minato arriving to the battlefield and all (chapter 630). No changes *seem* to have happened, but we'll need to wait a little longer to find that out.

Comment: @JNat - Sure, though he _just_ arrived with the others. We didn't have time to find out if anything changed...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of the current chapter (630), it is still not known if the Kyuubi's chakra was released from the Shinigami's stomach. It is possible that it is the **gift** that Minato is referring to when the kages and Sasuke's group are about to go to the battlefield.

[image: From chapter 627, page 16]

<sup>From chapter 627, page 16</sup>

Comment: when you mention that gift from Minato to his son Naruto, it makes sense if this will be the half of the kyuubi's chakra. We only have speculations but i think this is the nearest answer.

Comment: Chapter 631 seems to refute this speculation - I would say the big present is Sasuke.

Comment: This answer may need an update due to the recent developments in the plot.

Answer (score 9):

The latest chapter (631) shows:

> [Minato cloaked in the Kyuubi chakra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77N6j.jpg), in the same manner that Naruto is when using it.
>  This suggests that the half he has sealed away in himself is still there, in him and he has full use of it.

Answer (score 4):

We don't know what happened to it. It might be possible that it was released, and it might also be possible that it's sealed within Minato (if you remember, he sealed it within himself before he died).

I'm guessing that it won't go unnoticed, but I'm guessing we'll just have to wait and see.